# Custom TableViewCell with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a Destination View Controller that allows you to edit information displayed in the TableViewController..I am attempting to set this up in a custom cell..I have my UITableViewCell file with the custom property class and I also have my Model Class for the Core Data with the attributes.  I managed to get my root table view controller to show the custom label when I add a **NEW** player but once I click on the cell and edit it in the new view controller it goes back to the default on the table view.  I believe it has something to do with this code but I can not figure it out.

my NsManagedObject Subclass

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *playerFirstName;
```

I have a pointer to my Player Class of currentPlayer in my viewcontroller.h file and the firstnameTextfield is my UITextField

```
-(IBAction)doneEditing:(id)sender {

_currentPlayer.playerFirstName = firstnameTextField.text;

AppDelegate *myApp = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]'
[myApp saveContext];

}
```

**Update**

I believe this is my line of code that is the problem after messing with it

```
_currentPlayer.playerFirstName = firstnameTextField.text;
```

how do I get the currentPlayer pointer to go to my playerNameCell property in my customcell class

Comment: sorry if my terminology is off I am still learning

Comment: When you go back to the main view, are you reloading the row (or table) to display the new data?  (For example `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: I am using [self.tableView beginUpdates] on the -(void)controllerWillChangeContent method and didChange method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
- (IBAction)newPlayer {
  _currentPlayer = (Player*) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
}
```

The `_managedObjectContext` should be passed to the view controller from the app delegate or some other view controller.